# ImportError: No module named _caffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I am working on this [caffe branch](https://github.com/nshaud/DeepNetsForEO) ,after the installation, I can find the libcaffe.so and libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc4 in the /caffe/build/lib.

However when I tried to import caffe, an error called "ImportError: No module named _caffe"

```
sys.path.insert(0,CAFFE_ROOT+"/python")
import caffe
```

I read some other notes with similar problems, which says `_caffe.so` should be in the `/python` folder after `make pycaffe`, but in fact in the `/python` folder i could find any `_caffe.so` and I could not use `make pycaffe` which says '`no rule to make target pycaffe` '

Comment: try `make py`. The Makefile you are using should have a rule for `pycaffe`.

Answer (score 0):

_caffe.so should be in python/caffe/ if you build directly with make (i.e., create Makefile.config with your desired configuration), and under /lib when using cmake.
If you don't `find <caffe-root-directory> -name _caffe.so` anything, it might point on cmake not finding your python libraries. Are you using a special Python distribution? Maybe you have only Python 3 but python_version is set to 2?
If you build with cmake, make sure you define -DBUILD_python=1 and verify that you see Python on cmake's resultant configuration.
(Look for

```
--   BUILD_python      :   ON
```

And something like

```
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.12)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--   NumPy             :   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
```

)